# Does port-fowarding expose true ip when using a VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I have a commercial VPN (PIA) that allows port forwarding. As far as I've read this is required in order for remote desktop connection to work.

The question is whether port forwarding allows the RDP destination to know my true IP or not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, with port forward the "destination" will not know the "true" public IP from your router or whatever device establishes the internet connection to your ISP. Hiding the actual IP of the end node is - in laymen's terms - the whole purpose of port forwarding. It basically works the same as port forwarding on your router which also won't reveal the IP's inside your LAN either.

**Note** that that port forward is only required if you want to access your computer **from** the internet. I assume from your question that you are trying to RDP into a "destination". For that, you don't need port forward on your VPN.

But even if you are trying to reach your computer you can use an alternative remote access client like Teamviewer or Anydesk which does not require any port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding is done on your computer and allows access to your computer.
It requires knowing your public IP in order to access your router from outside
in the internet, the router then forwards the connection to your computer.

If you're using a VPN, it protects your computer and gives you an IP address
that is different from your public IP, so you become anonymous with an
IP that has no meaning and doesn't identify your location or yourself.

These two features contradict each other, as port-forwarding to work
requiring knowing your public IP, while VPN protection hides your public IP,
so they cannot work together.

A port-forwarding VPN is then a VPN that allows your computer to be
*accessed by its public IP* on the forwarded port, while still being
protected by the VPN for all other cases.

In other words, the forwarded port is an entrance to your computer that
bypasses the VPN. It has nothing to do with the VPN and suffers from
all the dangers that come from exposing your computer port directly to the
entire internet without any protection except that provided by the
software on your computer that is listening on this port.

Comment: The question seems to be about port forwarding _via the VPN_ (i.e. NAT rules on the PIA VPN gateways) rather than the physical gateway.

Comment: @user1686: My answer is that there is no port-forwarding via the VPN, only bypassing the VPN. A port-forwarding VPN allows such bypass.

Comment: But there _is_ port-forwarding via VPN. In this case PIA offers it as a service, so that clients could connect from outside to the _PIA-issued_ address (not the local ISP-issued one).

Comment: @user1686: The [PIA port-forwarding](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/how-do-i-enable-port-forwarding-on-my-vpn) is done via one designated PIA server, but seems to require turning off the VPN itself for doing that. I didn't find what the term port-forwarding VPN itself really seems to promise (at least in my eyes) in any VPN product where I went into the fine details.

Comment: The page just says the option change doesn't become effective until the VPN is switched off then on again. I've heard of people using this kind of feature for regular SSH/RDPing into their VPN-connected PC or NAS, as well as for hosting game servers at home (as a workaround for CGNATs that prevent "normal" port-forwarding), and even for hiding the location of BitTorrent tracker sites (to avoid takedowns)... Though it seems that PIA offer only a single automatically-selected port per client with zero customizability (e.g. VPN_IP:36346 forwarded to internal :36346 in the shown example).

Comment: @user1686: They are all just patches aimed for adding "port-forwarding" to the feature-list. PIA does better than most by hiding the public IP address, but this is not comparable to port-forwarding on the router (nor is this technically possible).

Comment: It's _exactly_ like port-forwarding on the router (PIA's VPN gateway is the router in this situation), and I know it's technically possible because I've implemented it on my personal VPNs, with the same `iptables -j DNAT` that home routers use for "real" port-forwarding.